# Product rule of exponential matrix differentiation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-spaces, lie-groups, matrix-calculus

Let $X,Y$ be two $n\times n$ complex matrices. Consider the function $f(t)=e^{tX}e^{tY}$. Is it correct that $\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=Xe^{tX}e^{tY}+e^{tX}Ye^{tY}$?

Otherwise, how to prove that $X +Y$ is the tangent vector to $f(t) = e^{tX} e^{tY}$ at $1$?

Comment: of course the Leibniz rule stays true, and $\frac{d}{dt} A f(t) =  A \frac{d}{dt} f(t)$ but in general $e^{tX+tY} \ne e^{tX}  e^{tY}$. and you mean $X+Y = f'(0)$  ?

Comment: So $\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=Xe^{tX}e^{tY}+e^{tX}Ye^{tY}$ is correct in general? do you know a proof for it?

Comment: no need for a proof, write $g(t) = e^{tX}, h(t) = e^{tY}$, so $f(t)_{ij} = (g(t)h(t))_{ij} = \sum_k g(t)_{ik} h(t)_{kj}$ which is a $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ function. and the definition $e^{tX} = \sum_n (tX)^n / n!$ tells you that $\frac{d}{dt} e^{tX} = X e^{tX} = e^{tX}X$

Comment: Alright, Thanks :)

Comment: so $X e^{tX} e^{tY} + e^{tX} e^{tY} Y$ works too, and it gives $(X+Y) e^{t(X+Y})$ if $XY = YX$ (commute)

Comment: Does this prove  $Y e^{tY}  = e^{tY} Y$ in  general?

Comment: yes see the definition, $Y$ commute with $Y^n$

Comment: the difficulty is with $e^{XY}$ when $XY$ don't commute ! again always ask : is it commutative or not

Comment: Yea, but I was looking for a smooth map that is its derivative at 0 is the tangent vector $X+Y$ .. according to your answer any $e^{tX},e^{tY}$ work without having the property $XY=YX$